# What is the start up/initialization procedure when an iPhone app is started?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, initialization

I would elaborate it as follows :

**In what order are the different objects and nib files instantiated/initialized ?**

My understanding is as follows:

```
1) UIMainApplication function loads the main .nib file specified in info.plist.
2) This .nib file instantiates the Delegate object.
3) When the appDidFinishLoading method runs, it generally initializes the UIViewController object.
```

In general, a .nib file instantiates the objects connected to it and the objects instantiate/load the .nib file they have a IBOutlet in.

If this is too complex to explain here, please point me to an appropriate article.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your summary looks OK to me - what kind of detail were you looking for?

Comment: I am not sure if what I wrote is really how it happens. I am looking for a confirmation or an explanation of the general mechanism which is folllowed.